# Isomorphism between $V$ and $U$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, computer-science

Let there be $V =$ $\mathbb{R}[x]$ space of all polynomials with 1 variable with
real coefficients
 
$U$ = { $p(x) \in\ V|p(0)=0$ }, In other words: $U$ is a subset in V of all of the polynomials:

---

$a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} +......+ a_1x$

---

such that the free constant term equals to $0$

prove that $U$ and $V$ are isomorphic

---

> **MY APPROACH:**
>  I tried to build an injective ( one-to-one ) and
> Surjective ( onto ) linear transformation / map. it is easy to see that there
> is one, but it is not injective because to two polynomials, different
> in the constant term, have the same output. I have tried to "fix" this
> linear transformation but with no success at this moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show that the map $\mathbb R[x]\to U$ given by $f\mapsto f\cdot x$ is linear, injective and surjective.

*(It is the inverse to Timurs suggestion, but easier to handle IMHO.)*

Comment: I think both approaches are easy :)

Comment: @Christoph can you elaborate on this method?

Comment: @OmriBraha I can if you ask more specific questions. What's not clear? Have you tried doing what I suggested?

Answer (score 2):

Try linear map $A:U\rightarrow V$ such that $A(a_nx^n+...+a_1x)=a_nx^{n-1}+...+a_1$.

Comment: What about $a_0$ ?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Answer (score 0):

You want to define a map sending a polynomial in $V$, that is, something of the form $f(x)=c_0+c_1x+c_2x^2+\dots+c_mx^m$, to a polynomial in $U$, that is, a polynomial of the form $g(x)=a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+\dots+a_nx^n$ in a way that is injective. A way of thinking about what injectivity requires is that you don't want to lose any of the “distinctive” information that uniquely identifies the polynomial $f$. What does this “distinctive, identifying” information consist of? How may we define a polynomial which is in $U$ and which retains all of the distinctive information specific to $f$ (thus giving a $g$ which could not be the image of any other polynomial than $f$)?

Comment: Not sure if I fully understand, but in other words - we need to "fix" this linear map so that she will "remember to constant term $a_0$ and would not erase it

Comment: @OmriBraha Yes: a polynomial is exactly determined by the coefficients of each power of $x$, so we want a function which "remembers all the coefficients" whilst giving us a polynomial in $U$.